# I bought 200GB of ICloud Storage, iCloud Settings shows 200GB, but the iCloud Storage tab says I have 4GB

Tags: icloud, iphone, storage

When I try to backup my Iphone it will take more than two hours and still not be halfway completed. My phone is only 32Gb with 6GB of free space. What's the problem with my IPhone?

Comment: maybe you could share a snapshot of your screen showing your problem

Comment: Hi Brett, as @Zeus suggested, you should complement your answer with more information; as is stands now it's difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Also - the title & question body appear to be unrelated.

Comment: And this might help others https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277946/i-upgraded-my-5gb-icloud-storage-to-50gb-storage-and-its-not-showing

Answer (score 4):

Sign out of iCloud on your phone by going to Settings > iCloud > and tapping "Sign Out." Then sign back in. This will prompt your iCloud connection to update the information it is displaying. If it does not update, sign out of iCloud, restart your iPhone, and sign back in.

Additionally, you may want to download the Ookla Speedtest app from the app store, and check the speed of your internet connection, as that is the most likely culprit of a slow backup, but will be a separate question as it involves router settings, and/or your Internet Provider.