# I upgraded my 5GB iCloud storage to 50GB storage and its not showing

Tags: ios, icloud, storage

and not only is it not showing but 1.98€ was deducted from my account and not 99¢ as advertised.  I am loath to click again as they may deduct MORE money!? Anyone out there know why my iCloud storage isn't appearing?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to make sure Apple has provisioned your storage is to sign in to iCloud on a computer with a somewhat modern browser:

https://www.icloud.com/#settings

If the cloud doesn't see your storage, you have a billing and/or support question.

- https://support.apple.com/itunes

If the cloud does show your storage, you can get free support using the paid storage as an exception from AppleCare at:

- https://support.apple.com/ - choose your device that's not able to get the paid storage.

Comment: Thank you, yes I signed into iCloud on my laptop and it is not showing.  I will contact them through the link you have sent!

Comment: @JoannePaterson Good luck. If you have a computer, there's also the "report a problem" link with each purchase. Also the email receipt you get might have a support link. I use the one above, so it should get you to billing support rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting your devices. That usually updates the display of available iCloud storage.

As for the extra charge, are you sure it's not just a temporary hold? If it still shows 2€ in a few days you might want it call Apple support directly and have it sorted out.

Comment: Yes, just tried rebooting, nothing!  Exactly the same........

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my icloud storage from 5G to 50G, the icloud storage settings on my iphone6 changed. The iCloud storage status used to be located in Settings > General > Iphone and Icloud storage. Now after upgrading, the settings are located in Settings > YOUR NAME/ID > iCloud.

Comment: The change is probably the result of a recent iOS upgrade...